# How do i get value from string textBox in C#

Tags: c#

I am newbee here right now, i'm trying to solve my problem code but it's doesn't clear.
I want to get value from my string `textBox.Text`. initial textBox is `hmI7Segment1.Text`. it's has string Format as `Channel1.DV1.DB1.Level1`. i wish to convert `double` value from this string into `textBoxTarget.Text`.
so, here is code problem:

```
hmI7Segment1.Text = "Channel1.DV1.DB1.Level1";
TextBox txtBoxTarget = converted.Format [hmI7Segment1.Text] as TextBox;
```

if all of you have solution, please help me to solve my case. thanks for all of you are.

Marbun

Comment: The way this works, you try something, it does not work. Then you post your work with unexpected results, This is something that you can get from MS docs on the web

Comment: if the value of the textbox is `"Channel1.DV1.DB1.Level1` how are you going to convert this to a double, your q is very poorly asked. i suggest you put your actual code which complies, and then put comments as to what you would expect/wanting to do.

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand correctly you wish to convert a value of a textbox which is a string, to a double right?

In that case you can do something like this:

```
Var stringInput = textbox.Text;

If(double.TryParse(stringInput, out var doubleInput))
{
//Do something with the double value
}
Else
{
//Input is not a valid double value, handle it by showing an error or something
}
```

Also you didn't specify the technology of your UI, is it forms or wpf?

Hope this helps

Comment: private void btnSTART_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            try
            {
                //string c = "Insert into CobaRecord(target) Values ('" + txtBoxTarget.Text.ToString() + "')";
                string c = "Insert into CobaRecord(target) Values ('" + Convert.ToDecimal("Channel1.DV1.DB1.Level1") + "')";
                
                dosomething(c);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("ERROR" + ex);
            }
        }

Comment: first of all what is that exactly? care to break it down for the OP and explain it? also generally its not very efficient to throw exceptions for casting, its much better to use decimal.TryParse to convert a value to a decimal